# 658. Find K Closest Elements - for loop 'comp' comparison variable not updating as expected

Tags: python-3.x

So I am working on problem 658 'Find K Closest Elements'(https://leetcode.com/problems/find-k-closest-elements/), which asks to return a list from the given list, 'arr'. This return list will be the length of 'k' and will contain the 'k' # of values closest to the given 'x' value. I've created all the base cases and constraints, and am now stuck on the comparison part below:

I've created an empty list, 'a'. While the length of 'a' is not 'k', the function will go through the list and compare abs(i - x) < abs(comp - x), 'comp' starting at 'arr[0]' and updating to 'i' if the comparison is true. The problem is that the comparison is not working correctly. Here is an example case I'm trying to figure out:

`arr = [1,1,1,10,10,10]`, `k = 4`, `x = 9`

Below is the portion of the code I am focusing on:

```
    a = []
    comp = arr[0]
    iteration = 0
    i_index = 0
    while len(a) != k:
        for i in arr:
            comp_1 = abs(i - x)
            comp_2 = abs(comp - x)
            if comp_1 < comp_2:
                comp == i
                print(f"comp: {comp}")
        arr.pop(arr.index(comp))
        a.append(comp)
    return a
```

I am including the entirety of the code just in case below:

```
def findClosestElements(self, arr: List[int], k: int, x: int) -> List[int]:
    
    # Constraints
    if k < 1 or k > len(arr):
        return "k must be greater than 0 and less than the arr length"
    if len(arr) < 1 or len(arr) > 10**4:
        return "arr length must be greater than 0 and less than 10^4"
    if x > 10**4:
        return "x must be less than 10^4"
    if sorted(arr) != arr:
        return "arr must be sorted"
    for i in arr:
        if i < -10**4:
            return "arr item cannot be less than -10^4"
    
    
    #Variables 1
    begin = arr[:k]
    end = arr[-k:]
    
    
    # Base cases
    if len(arr) == k:
        return arr
    
    if x < arr[0]:
        return begin
    elif x > arr[-1]:
        return end
    
    try:
        x_index = arr.index(x)
        half_k = int(k/2)   
    #if k == x and x_index != None:
     #   return [x]
        # Captures all other lists that begin at arr[0] or end at arr[-1]
        if x_index - half_k < 0:
            return begin
        elif x_index + half_k > len(arr) - 1:
            return end
        # Create list out of interior of arr if necessary
        else:
            return arr[x_index - half_k : x_index + half_k]
   
    # Means x is not in arr
    except ValueError:
        a = []
        comp = arr[0]
        iteration = 0
        i_index = 0
        while len(a) != k:
            for i in arr:
                print(f"{iteration} - {i_index}:")
                print(f"i: {i}")
                print(f"comp_1: {abs(i - x)}")
                print(f"comp_2: {abs(comp - x)}")
                comp_1 = abs(i - x)
                comp_2 = abs(comp - x)
                if comp_1 < comp_2:
                    comp == i
                    print(f"comp: {comp}")
                i_index += 1
                print("\n")
            iteration += 1
            arr.pop(arr.index(comp))
            a.append(comp)
        return a
```

Comment: to confirm, with `x=9` and `k=4` are you expecting `[1,10,10,10]` which are the 4 closest values to `9` ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I am expecting [1, 10, 10, 10]

Comment: i posted an answer which i think is a good aproach.  it uses `minimum distance`, so is very different to the proposed aswer...

Answer (score 0):

I would take the approach of:

1. finding the shortest distance from `x` to the elements of `arr`.
2. sorting `arr` by the `distances`.

So, this is a good method:

```py
arr = [1,1,1,10,10,10]
k = 4
x = 9


distances = [abs(x - n) for n in arr]

Z = [a for _,a in sorted(zip(distances,arr))]

print(Z[:k])
```

result

```
[10, 10, 10, 1]
```